# file_prepare_directory does not seem to be creating a directory

Tags: php, drupal, filesystems

I am running this code, and not getting any errors, but the directory is not being created:

```
  $publicsys = 'public://sys';
  file_prepare_directory($publicsys, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
```

This is in Drupal - is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Sounds like a permission problem.  Are you using windows or linux?

Comment: Linux. I'm testing (and only testing!) with the parent directory (/files) with permissions 777, so I wouldn't think it's a permissions issue. I suppose maybe the parent of files could be the culprit?

Comment: Are you running apache? If so the default user that runs php is www-data and that user is probably not the owner nor in the group for the /files dir.  What is the output of `ls -la /files`?

Comment: [root@domain global.dmstage.sbak.us]# ls
files  settings.php
[root@domain global.dmstage.sbak.us]# ls -la /files
ls: cannot access /files: No such file or directory

Comment: Note that above, files the directory does exist.

Comment: That's odd.  What is output by `ls -la /`?

Comment: [root@domain sites]# ls -la /?
ls: cannot access /?: No such file or directory

True in both the files directory as well as parent of files directory.

Comment: I think this may be the nature of my problem: https://drupal.org/node/2102905

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (for **Drupal 7**)

You can solve this issue by defining your own [Stream Wrapper](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!stream_wrappers.inc/7).

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_stream_wrappers().
 */
function MYMODULE_stream_wrappers() {
  return array(
    'syspublic' => array(
      'name' => t("Default distribution files"),
      'class' => 'SysPublicStreamWrapper',
      'description' => t("Visible, readable and writeable local path"),
      'type' => STREAM_WRAPPERS_LOCAL_NORMAL,
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Default sys (syspublic://) stream wrapper class.
 */
class SysPublicStreamWrapper extends DrupalPublicStreamWrapper {
  public function getDirectoryPath() {
    return 'sites/default/files/sys';
  }
}
```

Via: [Writing Stream Wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/node/560424)